# Why is Expand greyed out for a selected path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My file is in AI format. It is a logo. The Expand option is grey out. The subset of Path are also greyed out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a graphic design question, more like Illustrator tech support and it's probably going to be closed. Check the help for what's on-topic here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I'm afraid your question will get closed because we cannot troubleshoot specific files. Could you edit additional details of how your file is set up in your question? Your file may be an AI format, but is the logo made of vectors or is it raster data?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's only 3 reasons...

1. You don't have a anything selected
2. What you *do* have selected is **not** a stroked path
3. The selection is expanded as far as it can be expanded

Comment: Thanks Scott. I guess it is num2. When i select it, the big square box appears over who graphics instead of the graphics itself being selected. Will try tonight if i can just select the graphic itself.